# "Formal English" - Can its meaning vary from place to place? From person to person?

Tags: meaning, formality

Can it be opinion based? Whenever I ask a question here about word usage in formal English, I will invariably get a comment saying "It depends on what you mean by formal English".  Isn't there an academic definition which is considered the "golden reference"? I mean, if a writer doesn't point out that he refers to a specific type of formality, everyone should assume that he refers to that "golden definition".

Answer (score 4):

It's a good question, because the answer is sometimes surprising to speakers of other languages.  The answer is **no**.  There is no English Academy, as there is l'Académie Francaise.

English language references typically describe **usage**, that is, what English speakers and writer actually use or used at one time.

There are of course references that are more or less authoritative on such questions. But English in general has few prescriptionists, telling people what English **should be**.  Rather, people who study English are more inclined to try to discover what English in fact **is**, in practice.

English-language dictionaries, for example, are almost always usage-based. They try to tell you what a given word means currently (or meant at different periods in the past), by this or that set of speakers (e.g. country, region, social class), in this or that social or technical context (scientific, colloquial, vulgar).

Even concepts such as whether something is *grammatical* in English ultimately make appeal to actual usage, if I'm not mistaken.  (I am no linguist; just an English speaker.)

Comment: You only need a distinct authoritative academie for a language that is in danger of l'extinction, and being overridden by other more popular languages.

Comment: In Italy, to save the language from extinction, there is  "The Accademia della Crusca"  (Academy of the bran), generally abbreviated as "La Crusca", an Italian society for scholars and Italian linguists and philologists established in Florence. It is the most important institution responsible for regulating the Italian language as well as the oldest linguistic academy in the world.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: That's not really fair, I think.  l'Académie Francaise existed even back when French pretty much dominated Western society (courts, governments, and ruling classes everywhere spoke & wrote French). But that was a time when what was right was dictated top-down. Now, one might think that the French Revolution would have changed all that. Alas... restoration.  On n'arrete pas le progres.

Comment: Why did French lose out to English as the lingua populara of North America? Is it because the French had lost their bearings in the void of an omnipresent paternal guardian. Or is it because, immigrants from Europe preferred the defective tongue of English rather than the yet another of the many domineering institutions, from which they had fled.

Comment: @BlessedGeek It wasn't about the immigrants from Europe preferring one language to another.  In 1763, after Britain's victory over France and Spain in the Seven Years' War, the treaty of Paris was signed and France lost most of its possessions in North America.  That was a turning point, where it became clear that North America would be English. (and immigrants would be living in an English speaking country)

Comment: But soon after, the rebels were in cahoots with the French to shoo the Brits. Surely that was good nuf reason to speak French. And then the Dutch came, and the Germans, the Scandies, the Russians, Italians, Jews, Ukrainians, Spaniards. And of course, the belligerently anti-English Irish. These people could have chosen to speak French.

Comment: They could not. Either they stuck to their mother tongue or they adopted English.  And if they didn't adopt the English language, their children did. After the Louisiania Purchase in 1803, it was all the U.S.A. from the Atlantic to the Rockies. And English Realm of Canada north of parallel 49 + Oregon and Washington state.  No room for other languages.